# 2D engine that uses Flash Platform classes?

Tags: unity, 2d, actionscript-3

I want to develop a 2D game for Android, but, I want to use Flash Platform's framework APIs, ex: `Sprite`, `Shape`, `Graphics`, `Bitmap` .. etc as I have already wrote my game in AS3 ..

Is there a 2D engine for Android that uses Flash Platform's framework APIs?

If not, does Unity use Flash Platform's framework APIs?

I know that I can Adobe AIR to port the game to android, but, I want it a native code based to avoid Adobe AIR player as a requirement ..

Any guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the brand new http://www.openfl.org/.

It uses the language Haxe which is based off of AS3 (the only difference I found is that constructors must be called `new` and not the class's name).
It's great because it compiles to Android, iOS, blackberry, flash, html5, windows, max, and linux. :D

When it compiled to Android it converts the Haxe files to C++ and then uses the NDK to bind everything together. It is HIGHLY optimized so the speed of Haxe generated code is very comparable to code written by hand.

A few popular flash game engines have been ported over as well. eg. (HaxePunk port of FlashPunk and haxe-flixel port of flixel).

For windows the best IDE for it is flashdevelop hands down. For linux it's vim with some plugins and I'm not sure for mac (sorry)

The website for the haxe language is here http://haxe.org/

Comment: As for openfl, dose it use flashplatform names? like sprite, addChild, Bitmap .. etc?

Comment: Wow, I just found that it implements original flash name packages, that's just a relief!

Comment: What exactly is the relationship between OpenFL and NME?

Comment: @ashes999 if you look at the blog on openfl.org there is a video and he explains it in detail there. Basically NME was a low level library for graphics in haxe. Basically OpenFL is a more professional and organize evolution of NME. For the most part it's the same, but now the team behind it is more organized. They will be rolling out more updates and adding more features so that one day OpenFL will replace flash all together... hopefully.